# Quiero crear un Procedure para consultar la columna nom_chof

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, lógica

Buenas Tardes deseo saber como crear un **PROCEDURE** para consultar la tabla Chofer en la columna nom_chof con la columna por nombre 'PATRICIO HERRERA' Teniendo esto avanzado pero desconosco como usar correctamente los inner join.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE PA_VIAJES_CHOFER
@cod_chof CHAR(4)
AS
SELECT V.nro_via, V.fec_via, V.hrs_sal,
R.cod_rut, R.des_rut, V.costo_via
FROM VIAJES V INNER JOIN RUTAS R
ON V.cod_chof = R.des_rut INNER JOIN Chofer C
ON V.costo_via = C.cod_chof
WHERE V.cod_chof=@cod_chof
GO
```

Teniendo estas tablas
[image: Con estos Datos quiero hacer el "procedure" para consultar mediante el nombre del chofer con "inner join"]

Answer (score 0):

Dayamon299, sigue la respuesta.

***1 - Crear la Query***

```js
SELECT 
V.nro_via,V.fec_via,V.hrs_sal,
R.cod_rut,R.des_rut,V.costo_via
FROM VIAJES V WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN RUTAS R WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON V.cod_rut = R.cod_rut
INNER JOIN CHOFER C WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON V.cod_chof  = C.cod_chof
WHERE C.cod_chof = 'C001'
```

***2 - Crear la PROCEDURE***

```js
USE <nombre de la base de datos>

CREATE PROCEDURE PA_VIAJES_CHOFER
  @cod_chof CHAR(4)
  
AS

BEGIN

SELECT 
V.nro_via,V.fec_via,V.hrs_sal,
R.cod_rut,R.des_rut,V.costo_via
FROM VIAJES V WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN RUTAS R WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON V.cod_rut = R.cod_rut
INNER JOIN CHOFER C WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON V.cod_chof  = C.cod_chof
WHERE C.cod_chof = @cod_chof

END
GO
```

***3 - Ejecutar la PROCEDURE***

nombre de la base de datos.dbo.PA_VIAJES_CHOFER 'C001' -- cod_chof

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***4 - Exhibir nombre*** 
Se quieres que el nombre y cod_chof salga tendrá que añadir las celdas correspondentes.

```
SELECT 
C.cod_chof,C.nom_chof,V.nro_via,V.fec_via,V.hrs_sal,
R.cod_rut,R.des_rut,V.costo_via
FROM VIAJES V WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN RUTAS R WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON V.cod_rut = R.cod_rut
INNER JOIN CHOFER C WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON V.cod_chof  = C.cod_chof
WHERE C.cod_chof = 'C001'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]